# Do we get something if Accepted Answers is more than some number?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, accepted-answer

I want know, 
If answers given by me are accepted and after reaching some number is there something I can get (e.g. Badge or Reputation)?

Comment: [shiny badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: There is no shiny badges?

Comment: @Rajneesh:  Bronze, Silver, Gold... All shiny...;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few badges if you manage to get numbers of 0 votes accepted answers like the [unsung hero golden badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) for more than 10 zero scored accepted answer and these have to be more than 25% of your total accepted answers. Also the [tenacious silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) for 5 zero scored accepted answers and these avec to be 20% of total accepted answers.

Other than that.... there is not much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the first to answer a question and the answer is accepted with a score of 10 or more you will earn you the Enlightened badge.

Any accepted answer with a score of 40 or more will earn you the Guru badge.

You can see the full list of [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for additional reference.

Comment: I am not saying about score. I am saying if total number of Accepted Answers(with and without score) reaches at some number, do we get something.

Comment: @RajneeshGaikwad No. Nothing special for reaching a particular number.